# For Each with internal activities Azure Datafactory

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to send the number of times the cycle was executed?

that is, I have a *For Each* that executes an ExePipeline and it has 6 activities and only to the last activity I need to send it the number of times that the *for each* was executed.

at the end of *For Each* it shows how much data "ItemsCount" entered but I couldn't call that value in the last activity of the pipeline.

someone to help me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depend on what you're using for your items in the foreach activity.
But for example, if your foreach activity is looping over the content of a file that you have retrieved by a previous lookup activity - you can get the count of these items by for example:

```
@activity('Lookup activity name').output.count
```